# SQL how to get root parent id

Tags: postgresql

I know this is has been asked a million times but I still can't find the answer that works for my use case.

My Python script prior to loading to PostgreSQL does a recursive run to extract data from an API. It creates a table with `id`, `parent_id` (with the very first run being `0`), and a `child_id`. When the script runs again, the previous run's `id` is the next run's `parent_id`. I also have a `run_count` column that states which iterative step the row was generated from.

In my table in PostgreSQL, I'm trying to add a `root_id` column that traces each `id` back to the original `id` where these other `id`s are generated from.

Imagine I have the following (but more variety where there's more than 1 `id` with a `0` `parent_id`):

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE test AS
SELECT 1 id, 0 parent_id, 2 child_id UNION ALL
SELECT 1,0,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,0,4 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,5 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,6 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,2,7 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,2,8 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,2,9 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,2,10 UNION ALL
SELECT 7,3,12 UNION ALL
SELECT 21,0,56 UNION ALL 
SELECT 21,0,16 UNION ALL 
SELECT 21,0,52 UNION ALL 
SELECT 56,21,38 UNION ALL 
SELECT 16,21,11 ;
```

I want to get this:

```
+---------+----------+
| root_id | child_id |
+=========+==========+
| 1       | 2        |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 3        |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 4        |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 5        |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 6        |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 7        |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 8        |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 9        |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 10       |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 12       |
+---------+----------+
| 21      | 56       |
+---------+----------+
| 21      | 16       |
+---------+----------+
| 21      | 52       |
+---------+----------+
| 21      | 38       |
+---------+----------+
| 21      | 11       |
+---------+----------+
```

One of the many things I've tried:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id, child_id
    FROM test
    WHERE parent_id = '0'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, t.child_id
    FROM test t
    JOIN cte ON cte.id = t.id
    WHERE t.parent_id <> '0'
)
SELECT *
FROM cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your join in the recursive part is wrong, you need to join between parent_id and child_id.

To carry over the ID of the root, just add it to the non-recursive part and carry it over in the recursive part:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id, child_id, id as root_id
    FROM test
    WHERE parent_id = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, t.child_id, cte.root_id
    FROM test t
      JOIN cte ON cte.child_id = t.parent_id
)
SELECT root_id, child_id
FROM cte
ORDER BY root_id
```

Note that it's typically better to identify the root with a `NULL` value in the `parent_id` column. That way you can define proper foreign keys in your table (I would also get rid of the `child_id` column and only store `id` and `parent_id`)

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=810dfea9b6aee72011be3e8bc914c56f)

Comment: The children `38` and `11` seem to be missing in the output of the online example. The example output has less rows than OP's expected output.